# Apache2 Reverse proxy forward / to subdomain

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I have a webserver on my network that I am accessing via a reverse proxy.  I can set up apache2 to forward correctly so that

`www.thesite.com/subdomain/` goes to `192.168.0.whatever`, however the hyper links on the served page go to places like `192.168.0.whatever/index.html` which when clicked go to `www.thesite.com/index.html` instead of `www.thesite.com/domain/index.html`

I'm not sure how to redirect root requests for this proxied webserver to be forwarded correctly outside of rewriting the webpage to remove the `/` and make the requests relative, which can lead to its own issues.

Answer (score 0):

What does your proxy-config look like? Did you include:

`ProxyPreserveHost on`

?